# Zero-dimensional rings are clean?

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra

Is every zero-dimensional commutative ring a clean ring? I think I have seen somewhere the "positive" answer to this question, but I don't know where! Would you please inform me of a reference in this regard, or give a solution. By a clean ring I mean one in which any element is a sum of a unit and an idempotent.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What is a clean ring?

Comment: See Corollary 11 here: http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1081/AGB-120004490

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1081/AGB-120004490, Corollary 11]. This is a basic paper for readers interested in commutative clean rings.